# Deserialized JSON type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' is not compatible with expected type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'

Tags: c#, json, json.net

When I run "Populate" after update the version of Newtonsoft.Json to 13.0.1 I get an  error:

'Deserialized JSON type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' is not compatible with expected type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.'

This is error happening from the added code:

```
private JToken? CreateJToken(JsonReader reader, JsonContract? contract)
        {
            ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull(reader, nameof(reader));

            if (contract != null)
            {
                if (contract.UnderlyingType == typeof(JRaw))
                {
                    return JRaw.Create(reader);
                }
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null
                    && !(contract.UnderlyingType == typeof(JValue) || contract.UnderlyingType == typeof(JToken)))
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            JToken? token;
            using (JTokenWriter writer = new JTokenWriter())
            {
                writer.WriteToken(reader);
                token = writer.Token;
            }

            if (contract != null && token != null)
            {
                if (!contract.UnderlyingType.IsAssignableFrom(token.GetType()))
                {
                    throw JsonSerializationException.Create(reader, "Deserialized JSON type '{0}' is not compatible with expected type '{1}'."
                        .FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, token.GetType().FullName, contract.UnderlyingType.FullName));
                }
            }

            return token;
        }
```

How can I handle this change?
I don't want to run over my Jobject to check every type.